# Where can one find the documentation for the LEGO Mindstorms Robot Inventor software?

Tags: mindstorms, programming, robot-inventor

Is the documentation (either official or unofficial) of the programming "language" for the LEGO Mindstorms Robot Inventor software available somewhere? Preferably online, without requiring the download of an application. (I have looked at [the official LEGO site for the Mindstorms product line](https://www.lego.com/en-de/themes/mindstorms/about), but found nothing there)

To elaborate, I'm looking for a resource detailing the available commands, their possible parameters, expected results, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Official Docs

### Word Blocks

The *Word Block Descriptions* for the block language (Scratch) are under *Help & Support* in the *Settings*.

[image]

*Settings* are found by clicking on the gear icon on the home page.

[image]

## Basic Python

For Python, there is a *Knowledge Base* on the side of the screen. Click the book icon to show or hide it.

[image]

### Advanced Python

There is also separate documentation for the [low-level Python APIs](https://lego.github.io/MINDSTORMS-Robot-Inventor-hub-API/) for advanced users.

## Unofficial Docs

- [Prime Lessons](https://primelessons.org/en/) has documentation for both SPIKE Prime and MINDSTORMS Robot Inventor.
- Laid Back Koala made PDFs for both word blocks and basic Python and [shared them on the Eurobricks forum](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/182548-some-ris-51515-docs/)

Answer (score 5):

Recently following web-page appeared:
https://lego.github.io/MINDSTORMS-Robot-Inventor-hub-API/

I learned it from David Lechner (https://github.com/gpdaniels/spike-prime/issues/7#issuecomment-850643719). I haven't seen an official announcement, but the URL implies it's from LEGO.

Comment: Well, it also says `Copyright (c) 2017-2021 - LEGO System A/S - Aastvej 1, 7190 Billund, DK` on the documentation license.